# PyCharm не видит библиотеку

Tags: python, pycharm

Установил BeaurifulSoap. Написано, что установка прошла успешна, но PyCharm так и не видит и пишет, что библиотека не найдена. В чем может быть ошибка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А при запуске ругается на import bs4?

Comment: Нет, не ругается. То есть сначала как будто видит, а потом пропадает.

Comment: Я конечно не эксперт, но правильно from bs4 import `BeautifulSoup` вроде как

Comment: И на счёт `R`, при установке PyCharm предлает поставить `R Language Support` пакет или поставьте отдельно, если Вам действительно нужен `R`

Comment: Я вижу вы работаете в `virtualenv`, вы устанавливали библиотека в пределах `virtualenv` или только глобально?